# ajax in laravel 4.2.* needs an example

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am working with laravel 4.2.* and i need to use ajax in my project, but its hard to understand with the working ajax in laravel. I am searching lots of questions on stack overflow but all are out of my requirement and with some hidden code.

Anybody provide me some basic example of laravel ajax, with routes, controllers and js code.

For e.g:

```
Request::ajax();
Route::???();

$.ajax({
    url: ???
})
```

Setting the Route of Ajax.

And which url pass in Ajax url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Route:

```
Route::get('post',array('as'=>'post','uses'=>'PostController@getAllPost'));
```

controllers: PostController.php

```
public function getAllPost(){
   $postData = DB::table('posts')->get()->toArray();
   return Response::json(array('success'=>true,'records'=>$postData),200);
}
```

js

```
$.ajax({
  url:'post',
  type:'GET',
  dataType:'json',
  //cache:false,
  success:function(data){
    if(data['success']) {
      $(data.records).each(function(i,item){
        console.log(item);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: please add some more info such as: Request::ajax() and also the js code. thanks